# How to use Test DPC to test App Restrictions while debugging app?

Tags: android

I am trying to test App Restrictions. When testing my app, I usually install a debug apk over USB. However, I am now trying to use Test DPC to ensure the app works correctly when restrictions are set by an MDM system.

I am able to download my app from the managed version of Google Play (accessible after Test DPC creates the work profile), but it seems that logcat cannot connect to this app.

How do I get Test DPC to manage the debug app I have installed over USB?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're using your Test DPC.  In the simplest case: 1) install a Test DPC on your device from Google Play, 2) Set the TestDPC app as the device owner, e.g.: `adb shell dpm set-device-owner "com.afwsamples.testdpc/.DeviceAdminReceiver"`.  Look here for details: https://source.android.com/docs/devices/admin/testing-setup.  I'm not sure why logcat can't connect after you've done this.  Q: Are you using Android Studio (to start the debugger, and view logcat)?  Or are you doing something else entirely?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate, but I can't seem to connect to my app if I've downloaded it from Google Play (which is what I seem to have to do for Test DPC to be managing it).

As for how I'm using Test DPC, I downloaded it, and then I had it set up a work profile.